# What are the $n$-th degree minimal polynomials for $L^p([-1,1])$?

Tags: measure-theory, polynomials, normed-spaces

It is known (even by me) that the Chebyshev polynomial of degree $n$ (of the first kind) is the minimal polynomial in the space $L^{\infty}([-1,1])$ for a fixed $n$ and leading coefficient $2^{n-1}$.

However, what are the minimal polynomials for the $p$-norm in general for a fixed $n$? Does there exist a general answer?

---

This is my first question here and I apologize if it is not up to par. Feel free to edit, migrate or close it if necessary.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Thanks for fixing my title, I was struggling with proper formatting and there's no title preview.

Comment: Quick googling shows this http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2046665?uid=3738936&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21100838157061

Comment: @Norbert So basically it's an open question besides the two kinds of Chebyshev polynomials and Legendre polynomials (I only read the first page, I don't have an account in JSTOR)? If so, I'd accept an answer from you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your question is an open problem, but there are partial answers.

Let's fix natural number $n$, and  $1<p\leq\infty$. By $T_{n,p}$ we denote polynomial of degree $n$ with leading coefficient equa to $1$ with minimal norm in $L_p([-1,1])$.

It is known that (see [On the Zeros of Polynomials of Minimal Lp-Norm
András Kroó and Franz Peherstorfer](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2046665?uid=3738936&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21100838157061))

- $T_{n,1}$ is the Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind, so
  $$
  T_{n,1}(x)=U_n(x)=\frac{\sin((n+1)\arccos(x))}{\sin(\arccos(x))}
  $$
- $T_{n,2}$ is the Legendre polynomial, so
  $$
  T_{n,2}(x)=L_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^nn!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n
  $$
- $T_{n,\infty}$ is the Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind, so
  $$
  T_{n,\infty}(x)=T_n(x)=\cos(n\arccos(x))
  $$

However we can force Chebychev polynomials to minimize weighted norms in $L_p([0,1])$ [[2]](http://www.springerlink.com/content/9l17296467472633/). In fact

- $T_n(x)$ have the smallest norm
  $$
  \Vert f \Vert=\left(\int\limits_{-1}^1(1-x^2)^{-1/2}|f(x)|^p dx\right)^{1/p}
  $$
  among polynomials of degree $n$ with leading coefficient $1$.
- $U_n(x)$ have the smallest norm
  $$
  \Vert f \Vert=\left(\int\limits_{-1}^1(1-x^2)^{(p-1)/2}|f(x)|^p dx\right)^{1/p}
  $$
  among polynomials of degree $n$ with leading coefficient $1$.

Comment: The link to the paper [2] at `springerlink.com` seems to be broken. Perhaps you could take a look, whenever possible...

Comment: It has been 10 years ago. I don't remember that paper.

Comment: Ah, not unexpected... Thanks for checking, though!

Comment: These results are in "Chebyshev Polynomials" by J. C. Mason and D. C. Handscomb.